# Phantomjs page.open multiple url's slows down

Tags: javascript, url, html, phantomjs

I have a set of URLs which I use page.open() to open. After processing the contents, I then call page.release() on the page and then call the function to open another page recursively. The webpage has javascript on it, and I test for a condition showing when the javascript has loaded results. The first page.open() call loads the JS in 1 second but all subsequent calls take about 6seconds. I am using page.release() and the pages loaded aren't blank and phantomjs is not crashing. I am wondering why this is happening. I've also tried using page.close()

```
doAnalysis = function (i) {
    var url = 'http://myurl.com'; 
    page.open(url, function(status) {
         //get html and process it
         page.release();
         doAnalysis(i++);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try creating the page variable inside the function:
`var page = require('webpage').create();`

See this [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/render_multi_url.js)